# Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() not working in CRM web resource

Tags: dynamics-crm

The recommended approach to get the api URL inside a Dynamics CRM web resorce:

```
Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()
```

Is not working. The javascript function fails when that method is called. If I replace it with

```
"https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com"
```

Then my code works. Any ideas why this method wouldn't work?

Comment: There is a known compatibility issue on `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx`. What's your Dynamics CRM version and which browser product/version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Henk! That's interesting - can you tell me more? My issue was solved as described below, but I definitely want to be familiar with any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses Andre and Henk. I actually solved the problem by prepending "parent." to the beginning:

```
parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()
```

This worked for

```
parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
```

also, which was broken before I added the "parent.". I found this one of the sample js files in the SDK, but I haven't found any documentation about why it works and when you need to use parent.

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx):

> Use the GetGlobalContext function when programming with web resources to gain access to context information. To get the GetGlobalContext function in your HTML web resource, include a reference to ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx.

From the sample of the same page:

```
<head>
    <title>HTML Web Resource</title>
    <script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's helpful. As I understand it, that function is specifically designed for web resources running in areas of the application where they don't have access to Xrm.Page. I would have tried it had I not found the solution below.